# First Release of Packages with cross dependencies

Tags: ros, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two packages to be released for ROS for the first time; `A` and `B`.
Package `B` has a dependency on Package `A`.  `B <-- A`

My current assumption is I need to bloom-release Package `A` first, and wait for it to be released publicly before I can submit the bloom-release for Package `B` since it has a dependency on Package `A`.

Does the ROS Build Farm only use the public 'rosdistro/rosdep' database for checking dependencies?
Or is the ROS Build Farm immediately aware of newly packages as possible dependencies once built?

Is there an existing process for releasing two independent packages simultaneously which have interdependencies?
If not, is there any estimation of the release pipeline?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238430/first-release-of-packages-with-cross-dependencies/) by [mdhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/27278/mdhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2016-06-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-29**:
If the two packages are in the same repository (ie: are released at the same time), then afaik you don't need to do anything special. Bloom should be able to resolve the dependency and release `A` and `B` in one go. This is all local, the buildfarm is not yet involved at that point.

**Comment by [mdhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/27278/mdhorn/) on 2016-06-29**:
Each package is in an independent repository unfortunately.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-30**:
Then I believe that what you described (release `A`, wait, then release `B`) is the only option left. Maybe @William can comment on this? Note that afaik, the farm uses the shadow repository, so you wouldn't need to wait on the sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If they're in the same repository then bloom can release them at the same time. If they are in different repositories then you need to wait until the release pull request of the first package is merged before releasing the second one. You don't have to wait for the build farm to build the package successfully or anything, just that the pr is merged. After the pr is merged it will be available via rosdep (which is actually via python-rosdistro) almost instantly.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3